# how a MDIchild can control another MDIchild in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have program that contains 3 forms.
one the parent and the other are children.
At first,the main form and child 1 will open and there are two buttons in child 1.
if user clicks on the first button,the second child form would be shown.
and if user clicks on the second button,the text of textboxes of second child would be stored in array of first child.

If there is any solution,please share that because I would be so thankful... :D

Regards,

Comment: you didn't try anything?

Comment: sry bro!!!! I wrote sth but its slow because I used panel not form.but its not a program,its just an example !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your title asks about controlling an MDI child from another: you can access the MDI child forms collection with the [`MdiChildren` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The parent form itself will be available from the child form through the [`MdiParent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Once you get the forms collection just look for the form you want, cast it to your typed form class and voila, you will have access to it. Here's an example of how you could fetch it on one line:

```
// assuming the desired form is loaded and unique
var otherForm = this.MdiParent.MdiChildren.OfType<YourFormType>().Single();
```

At this point, *controlling* the form will depend on how you expose its controls and properties.

Now, on creating a form from a button click, this should be a breeze. If you already know how to load your first child form, you know how to load a second one. If somehow you can't please share more details on the difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... .Since I'm new programmer,I ask you to give me a more clear example. For example in your example,I don't know what I should type in <yourformtype>...

Comment: @Massoud You are welcome. Since you're new here, I would like to advise that you mark this answer as the right one if it is. :)

Comment: @Massoud Share your code first then we'll start from there.

Comment: I wrote my app with panel not form so it is slow because it contain so many images. then I decided to use MDI. so now this question is start of my app!!!

Comment: @Massoud I'm afraid this isn't how StackOverflow works. You may expect help with a precise problem you are facing but that's it, no one will write your app for you. I suggest that you do some research and start trying things. From there, you will likely be granted help.